# My reanimated works more than once. How can make this animation work for once?

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated

I'm trying to make my tabbar dissappear while scrolling down with animation. onScroll sends boolean value if last y coord is bigger than current y coord its scrolling up and otherwise scrolling down. If I continue to scroll down onScroll still sends true value to my function and animaton works more than once. How can i disable position so only toValue is gonna work and my function will not trigger again and again while returning boolean value is same from onScroll.

```
function runTiming(value, dest) {
    const clock = new Clock();
    const state = {
        finished: new Value(0),
        position: new Value(0),
        time: new Value(0),
        frameTime: new Value(0),
    };

    const config = {
        duration: 200,
        toValue: new Value(0),
        easing: Easing.inOut(Easing.cubic),
    };

    return block([

        cond(clockRunning(clock), 0, [

            set(state.finished, 0),
            set(state.time, 0),
            set(state.position, value),
            set(state.frameTime, 0),
            set(config.toValue, dest),
            startClock(clock),
        ]),
        timing(clock, state, config),
        cond(state.finished, debug('stop clock', stopClock(clock))),
        state.position,
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to the onScroll event being fired more than once.

I just coded this yesterday and will give you the code that is working and has been tested:

```
export const throttle = (func, limit) => {
  let inThrottle
  return function() {
    const args = arguments
    const context = this
    if (!inThrottle) {
      func.apply(context, args)
      inThrottle = true
      setTimeout(() => inThrottle = false, limit)
    }
  }
}

class MainComponent extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.offset = 0;
    this.isAnimatingMenu = false;
    this.onScroll = this.onScroll.bind(this)
  };

  onScroll = throttle(event => {
    const currentOffset = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
    const direction = currentOffset > this.offset ? 'down' : 'up';
    const diff = currentOffset - this.offset;

    if (direction === 'down' && diff > 9 && !this.isAnimatingMenu) { 
      this.isAnimatingMenu = true
      this.onHideMenu(() => this.isAnimatingMenu = false)
    }

    if (direction === 'up' && diff < -9 && !this.isAnimatingMenu) {
      this.isAnimatingMenu = true
      this.onShowMenu(() => this.isAnimatingMenu = false)
    }

    this.offset = currentOffset;    
  }, 75)

  render() {
    <FlatList 
      windowSize={1}
      bounces={false}
      style={styles.flex1}
      scrollEventThrottle={75}
      onScroll={this.onScroll}
      renderItem={this.renderItem}
      data={this.deriveHomeWidgetsDataFromProps()}
    />
  }
}
```

In the functions `onHideMenu` and `onShowMenu` call your animation function to show/hide the menu. `onScroll` can be implemented on `ScrollView` or `SectionList` aswell. If you need more help let me know.